# Kohanim unfit to serve

Tags: rambam, beis-hamikdash

The Rambam in [Hilchot Biat Hamikdash, Perek 8, Halachah 15](http://www.chabad.org/library/article_cdo/aid/1008249/jewish/Biat-Hamikdash-Chapter-8.htm), writes that a Kushite is unfit to serve in the Mikdash.  To quote

> ...שמונה בעור הבשר ואלו הן. הכושי
>
> There are eight involving the skin. They are:
>
> a) a Kushite;
>
> b) an albino whose skin is white like cheese;
>
> c) one who is red-skinned like scarlet;
>
> d) one who has pure blotches on his skin,17 i.e., [the appearance of]
>   the skin changed because of an internal factor, like a bohak;18
>
> e) [the appearance of] the skin changed because of an external factor,
>   like the scarring of a burn; this is also one of the distinguishing
>   marks that are pure [with regard to tzara'at];19
>
> f) one who has a facial mole that has hair, even if it is not the size
>   of an isar,20 but rather of the smallest size;21
>
> g) one who has a facial mole the size of an isar or more;22h) one
>   afflicted with warts, [when] a person's flesh or skin should distend
>   or the fluids in the skin should distend to any part throughout the
>   body, this is a blemish.

What are the ramifications of this law? What kind of modern people would theoretically be unfit to serve in the Mikdash?

Comment: Why not ask about all three of his initial examples?? "There are eight [blemishes] related to skin: too dark, too light, too red..."

Comment: I'm not sure what the question is. What kind of people are unfit? The ones he names in that piece you just quoted.

Answer (score 1):

The Gemara ([בכורות מד:](http://www.toratemetfreeware.com/online/f_01135.html#HtmpReportNum0085_L2)‏) which is the source of this Rambam, defines כושי as `כל שמראיו חשוכין`  anybody with a dark complexion. That would seem to exclude anybody who isn't Caucasian-looking (for lack of a better term).

However, Rashi there defines כושי as `שהוא שחור ככושי` somebody as black as a Kushite. And in [ברכות נח:](http://www.toratemetfreeware.com/online/f_00878.html#HtmpReportNum0113_L2)‏ as `שחור הרבה` very black.

The Bartenura says on that Mishna in [בכורות  (Mishna 7:6)](http://www.toratemetfreeware.com/online/f_01297.html#HtmpReportNum0053_L2) say  `הכושי. שחור` - i.e. black.

That would seem to exclude from service those who look black - and possibly include those *Africans* (for lack of a better term) who are dark brown.

The only other place I recall discussing complexion is in [נגעים (Mishna 2:1)](http://www.toratemetfreeware.com/online/f_01370.html#HtmpReportNum0006_L2) where it says:

> רַבִּי יִשְׁמָעֵאל אוֹמֵר, בְּנֵי יִשְׂרָאֵל, אֲנִי כַפָּרָתָן, הֲרֵי הֵן כְּאֶשְׁכְּרוֹעַ, לֹא שְׁחוֹרִים וְלֹא לְבָנִים, אֶלָּא בֵּינוֹנִיִּים

Jews are neither black nor white, but look like [boxwood](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Buxus), a type of cedar. Making it sound that anything too light or dark is not typical. This is relevant, because the "coloring issue" that makes a Cohen unfit is because he stands out from the other Cohanim, as the Bartenura teaches us in [בכורות  (Mishna 7:1)](http://www.toratemetfreeware.com/online/f_01297.html#HtmpReportNum0048_L2) `אָמַר קְרָא (וַיִּקְרָא כא) כָּל אִישׁ אֲשֶׁר בּוֹ מוּם מִזֶּרַע אַהֲרֹן, הַשָּׁוֶה בְזַרְעוֹ שֶׁל אַהֲרֹן יַעֲבֹד, וְשֶׁאֵינוֹ שָׁוֶה בְזַרְעוֹ שֶׁל אַהֲרֹן לֹא יַעֲבֹד` (based on the Gemara in ([בכורות מג.](http://www.toratemetfreeware.com/online/f_01135.html#HtmpReportNum0082_L2)‏) - those Cohanim who look alike may serve, those who look different may not.

So if a lot of Cohanim have a darker-than-Caucasian complexion, they may be accepted as *normal looking*. (And then you could ask: If a huge majority of Cohanim are *dark*, would the lighter ones be invalidated?)

For some reason, previous generations decided to keep this vague; we'll have to see what Eliyahu Hanavi and Moshiach decide, when it becomes a practical issue. בִּמְהֵרָה בְּיָמֵינוּ

Comment: Note plenty of Caucasians would be excluded too according to the next line in the Rambam. Jews were middle Eastern ie pretty tan colored or "ceder colored".

Comment: Does anyone suggest that we're talking medical abnormalities? Just as we would for an albino or someone with red-colored skin.